# data node empty in Configmap on helm install

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

These are my helm charts:

```
# helm/templates/configmap.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  mycfgmap: |-
{{ .Files.Get (printf "environments/configmap.%s\n.yaml" .Values.namespace) | indent 4 }}
```

```
# helm/environments/values.dev.yaml

namespace: dev
```

```
# helm/environments/configmap.dev.yaml

MY_ENV_VARIABLE_1: "true"
```

This is how I am installing my helm charts:

```
helm install --dry-run --debug --create-namespace -n dev -f helm/environments/values.dev.yaml my-test-release helm
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
# Source: helm/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  mycfgmap: |-
---
```

I am expecting this to be in the data node (as defined in my `configmap.dev.yaml`):

```
MY_ENV_VARIABLE_1: "true"
```

Please note that I have alredy tried these for `helm/templates/config.yaml`:

```
{{ .Files.Get (printf "../environments/configmap.%s\n.yaml" .Values.namespace) | indent 4 }}

# and

{{ .Files.Get (printf "environments/configmap.%s.yaml" .Values.namespace) | indent 4 }}
```

and it doesn't work. I have also looked at similar questions answered on SO, but my problem seem to be something else.

Comment: The `\n` seems wrong; it would put a newline into the filename.  I'd expect the very last option to work, though.  Are there any errors or other output, or just blank content?  (Also consider using `.Release.Namespace` rather than duplicating it in Helm values.)

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, it's just the blank content under configmap. Also, I agree `{{ .Release.namespace }}` should be used instead of hard coding the name

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your message that the file you have used for configmap yaml is `# helm/environments/config.dev.yaml`. Please rename it to `configmap.dev.yml`. And change your `printf` statement like below. Once you make these changes, things should work fine.

```
{{ .Files.Get (printf "environments/configmap.%s.yaml" .Values.namespace) | indent 4 }}
```

Comment: Please note that `# helm/environments/config.dev.yaml` is a typo. I have corrected that in my question. Also, I mentioned in my question that I have already tried that `printf` statement but it doesn't seem to work